# hide CSS page by click on other link

Tags: css, hide, hyperlink, show-hide

I was wondering, I got this code:

```
<li><a href="#home">Home</a></li> 
<li><a href="#link1">Link 1</a></li>
```

And this code in CSS:

```
#link1
{
display: none;
}

#link1:target
{
display: block;
}
```

Also some design-stuff but it's included in the li part in my CSS code, so it's not needed here.

**Right now,** my homepage is always visible. How do I make the home-part disappear when I click on "Link 1"? Because now the content of "Link 1" appears beneath the home-content, instead of in its place (for which the home-content would have to disappear, which I said, it doesn't)

I'd like to keep everything in one html-document, that's why I'm using CSS, instead of linking to another page, which would probably make this a lot easier.

If I'm not clear or you need some extra code just tell me, but please do tell me what is unclear then. Thanks :]

Comment: This is not doable in CSS alone since it can not traverse upwards in the DOM (yet). Check the javascript answer below on how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried javascript/jQuery at all?

```
$('#link1').click(function() 
{
  $('#home').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Give a try to jQuery tabs. Very easy to use and it will do it all for you.
http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/